# Does ELMAH works in medium trust environment

Tags: elmah, medium-trust

I've a ASP.NET MVC website running successfully for a while. The hosting company suddenly changed the trust level to medium and I'm started to see 503 errors strangely. I'm using Fluent NHibernate and ELMAH. I removed the Fluent NHibernate dlls and the calls but I'm still seeing errors and I hope it is due to ELMAH. Does ELMAH works in medium trust environment? Do I need to do some tweaking to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Elmah can be configured to use many different providers you may not have a problem with Elmah, but rather with some satellite assembly that is loaded alongside. So investigate your Elmah configuration as well as the assembly itself

There are also some dependencies that Elmah have that are not Medium trust compatible, such as [SqlLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626704/using-elmah-in-medium-trust). If this is the case for you the solution linked to is to rebuild Elmah without the dependencies.