# ELMAH / Server 2008 / IIS 7.5 / MVC 2 : 500 - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5, elmah, global-asax

I've been trying to resolve a 404 error received when trying to access ELMAH.axd. The ELMAH email functionality worked, but I could not navigate to the axd. Now, I'm getting 500.22 - Internal server error. Can someone spot the error in my code or suggest some recourse short of disabling ELMAH?

```
 <sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    <section name="errorTweet" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorTweetSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
  </sectionGroup>

<system.web>

<authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="ViewOnly,Admins" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>

<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ElmahConnectionString" />
    <!-- email configured here -->
</elmah>

<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorTweet" type="Elmah.ErrorTweetModule, Elmah"/>
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
</httpModules>

<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
  <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />    
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
</modules>
```

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

And in Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

I'm using a database to record ELMAH data.

What am I missing? I've read so many posts and it seems that there is no one right answer, I suppose given the several ways applications and servers can be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing definitely looks like a configuration issue.

*HTTP 500.22 - "An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode."*

I found [this link](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/12/08/IIS-7.0-Breaking-Changes-ASP.NET-2.0-applications-Integrated-mode.aspx) that provides some details on breaking changes in II7.  More details specific to the web.config can be [found here](http://arcware.net/use-a-single-web-config-for-iis6-and-iis7/).

Do you have the ELMAH handler configured in the system.webSever section of your web.config? If not, I believe adding it should resolve your issue:

```
<handlers>
     <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I can see is that:

1. You are trying to make ELMAH logging errors into a database, but the connection string `ElmahConnectionString` is not defined anywhere. BTW, you should start trying to use `logPath="~/App_Data"` instead; if all runs well, then implement the database connection.
2. `deny users = "*"` means deny everyone; `deny users = "?"` means deny unauthenticated users. I guess what you want is the latter.

Comment: Hi rsenna, I do have the configuration setting for the database. I didn't display it.  <add name="ElmahConnectionString" connectionString="Data     <add name="ElmahConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=echoarchivedb;Initial Catalog=ELMAH_ERROR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=webappadmin;Password=mypassword"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: When I browse the application on the IIS 7.5 server, I get this message: HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode. I wonder what setting does NOT apply and why, if that has been detected, can't the server tell us what setting it can't apply? Thanks.

Comment: From my machine, errors can be logged into ELMAH_ERROR. So I know that is working properly.

Comment: OK. So I guess Jonathan S.' answer is closer to the real issue. I've followed the links he's posted, and I've found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939783/how-to-configure-elmah-to-work-with-windows-azure-i-get-a-404-on-elmah-axd/977956#977956) answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: OK - I reverted to an earlier web.config. Now, I get a logon window, which doesn't let me logon...so I cancedl and get the message:  401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the security as a test?  With issues like these, I usually have better luck trying to get the most basic implementation in place before adding things.

Answer (score 0):

What mode is your application pool running in (classic or integrated)? I had this problem and found that Elmah started working after I change my app pool to integrated mode.