# Cloud not access elmah.axd on Azure application

Tags: azure, elmah, form-authentication

I created a web application and added an ELMAH module for error logging. It was working with my local development environment: when i access URL http://localhost:52584/elmah.axd it shows me a valid page:

[image]

When i testing it after uploading on azure portal it shows me an error page:

[image]

Is there any specific configuration i need to do for Azure platform?

Also i have done form authentication on my web application, so when I try elmah.axd it will redirect to login page and i need to login first. I would like to remove that form authentication, particularly for elmah.axd. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify? Does ELMAH work if you log in?

Comment: Also, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939783/how-to-configure-elmah-to-work-with-windows-azure-i-get-a-404-on-elmah-axd - specifically the remarks on remote access.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee It didn't work even after login right now, same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nuget package does not add the following important lines to web.config resulting in 403 error.

```
<elmah>  
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/app_data/elmah" />
</elmah>
```

This should fix the 403. 
Also you may want to restrict the access to error logs by

```
<add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="/admin/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Comment: where i have to put this 2 lines exactly in web.config?

Comment: You can put it anywhere in configuration. Probably just before the last tag </configuration>.

Comment: after adding 2 lines of elmah section it's worked but as i would like to know that as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939783/how-to-configure-elmah-to-work-with-windows-azure-i-get-a-404-on-elmah-axd it it necessary to add enableNativeCodeExecution="true" to .csdef file of azure project? because i have uploaded current project with that setting

Comment: You do not need to set enableNativeCodeExecution to true, as that is the default (that other SO answer is from 2009 and things were different then). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd573353.aspx for more information.